# Using pinia with vue facing decorator throwing "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'useCoreStore' before initialization"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, pinia

In my [`vue-facing decorator`](https://github.com/facing-dev/vue-facing-decorator) to my current project I am having issue setting up pinia

My component looks like the sample mentioned here: https://facing-dev.github.io/vue-facing-decorator/#/en/quick-start/quick-start?id=introduction

I checked decorators like `@Setup`  is working completely fine which confirms that `vue-facing decorator` is correctly setup.

This is how I am setting up pinia.

```
export const useCoreStore = defineStore('core', {
  state: () => ({
    navCollapsed: false,
  }),
  getters: {},
  actions: {},
});
```

In the component

```
import { useCoreStore } from '@/core';
import { mapActions } from "pinia";

@Component({
  setup() {
    const store = useCoreStore();
    debugger;
    return { useCoreStore: store };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(useCoreStore, [ "setNavCollapsed" ])
  }
})
class AppHeader extends Vue {
```

When I run this in my browser, I get the error like and the it doesn't get to debugger.
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'useCoreStore' before initialization`

If I comment out mapActions.

```
//...mapActions(useCoreStore, [ "setNavCollapsed" ])
```

I can see my debugger getting hit.

What's the correct way to use pinia with vue-facing-decorator package ?

Comment: It's likely specific to your setup. Please, provide a way to reproduce. I'd expect it to be done the way you did in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an import issue.

Instead of accessing the store `@/core` I had to use `@/core/core.store`;